# pass answer to git command

Tags: linux, command-line, password, git

I try to get "git pull". It is asking for username and password. How i can automate it?

```
➜ git:(master) git pull
Username for 'http://127.0.0.1': username
Password for 'http://username@127.0.0.1': password
```

I try this but username is passed before it was asked by git

```
/bin/sh -c 'cd /var/www/ && git pull | echo username | echo password'
```

Comment: try username/password in url syntax, e.g. `git pull https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git`

Answer (score 1):

If you had access via ssh instead of https you could use ssh keys.

You can also use the following URL notation like Andrew Pi suggested:

```
git pull https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```

and it's also possible to just set the user, so it only prompts for the password:

```
git pull https://username@github.com/username/repository.git
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the password in a config file and use the same file as 'source /path-to-config-file.If GIT_USERNAME and GIT_PASSWORD is the variable then use

```
git clone http://$GIT_USERNAME:$GIT_PASSWORD@some_git_server.com/project.git
```

Check the output using

```
success=$?
```

or

```
echo SUDO_PASSWORD | sudo -S su -c "USERNAME PASSWORD" | git pull; exit"
```

Comment: The password will be expanded by the shell before the command is executed, and thus will be visible to all users on the same machine.

Answer (score -2):

You could try

```
/bin/sh -c 'cd /var/www/ && echo -e "username\npassword" | git pull'
```

that is, place the `echo` command before the `pull` command. This is how the `echo` is passed to the `pull` command.